# Android build error on react native 0.55.2

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

Trying to run a project on react-native 0.55.2 using "react-native run-android" but getting the following error

[image: screenshot]

```
Configure project :rn-fetch-blob
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed:
android.useDeprecatedNdk
NdkCompile is no longer supported



> Task :react-native-ble-manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
E:\premisehq-mobile-react-native\node_modules\react-native-ble-manager\android\src\main\java\it\innove\LollipopPeripheral.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: package android.support.annotation
E:\premisehq-mobile-react-native\node_modules\react-native-ble-manager\android\src\main\java\it\innove\LollipopPeripheral.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
 ^
  symbol: class RequiresApi
E:\premisehq-mobile-react-native\node_modules\react-native-ble-manager\android\src\main\java\it\innove\LollipopScanManager.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: package android.support.annotation
E:\premisehq-mobile-react-native\node_modules\react-native-ble-manager\android\src\main\java\it\innove\LollipopScanManager.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
 ^
  symbol: class RequiresApi
Note: E:\premisehq-mobile-react-native\node_modules\react-native-ble-manager\android\src\main\java\it\innove\LegacyScanManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem few months back. There was a difference in **Android SDK**.
Try to find out the targeting version of SDK in build.gradle. The version of Android SDK and app's targeting version should be same.
Hope this will help you.